# Having difficulty with when I try to pass variables through functions

Tags: sql, perl

I'm quite new at Perl and doing some exercises that require me to input and output variables through functions. I created the same script using global variables, and it worked, but after I tried to use my, and set everything to strict I ran into a bunch of problems. Is my syntax off? Or something much more fundamental? Any help would be appreciated:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;
use Getopt::Std;

getopt('s:');
my $opt_s;
my $search = $opt_s;
my @array = &function1();
my $arrayvalue = &function2();
&function1($search);
&function2(@array);
if (&function2(@array) != 0 {
    print "no values found for '$search'","\n"};

sub function1 {

my search = $_[0];
our $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=database, "user", "password")
    or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sql = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT Player from Players_Sport where Sport like '$search'")
or die $DBI::errstr;
my @array = map { $_->[0] } @$sql;
$dbh->disconnect
    or warn "Disconnection failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
return @array;
}

sub function2 {
my $arrayvalue=()
my @array = $_[0];
print join("\n", @array, "\n");
if(scalar (@array) == 0) {
    $arrayvalue = -1;
}
    else {$arrayvalue = 0;
};
return $arrayvalue;

}
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean. I have the cost posted.

Comment: He means to post the output of the code, aka what the interpreter tells you when you attempt to run the script.

Comment: Gotcha. This is my first week coding/scripting, so sorry about being green around the edges.

Use of uninitialized value $search in concatenation (.) or string at script 5-6.pl line 22

Use of uninitialized value @array[0] in join or string at script 5-6.pl line 33

Comment: @user2361820 - the code as poste would not be able to run, as it doesn't compile (no semicolon after first statement in `function2`. Please copy/paste actual code from your file that you are running. Also, in the question itself, post the error message you are dealing with.

Comment: There are an insane amount of errors in the code posted.  Many syntactical errors as well as errors that indicate a fundamental misunderstanding of what you're actually doing...One example, in `sub function1`, the first thing you do is call upon `$_[0]`, yet when you first call the function, you don't pass it anything.

Comment: @DVK I was the one who upvoted you!

Answer (score 4):

There are many many problems with this code (from major ones like not being compilable, so I don't even know how you get the runtime errors), to minor stylistic issues.

However, since you talk about variable passing, I will zero in on that piece.

---

Here's where you call your functions:

```
my @array = &function1();
my $arrayvalue = &function2();
&function1($search);
&function2(@array);
```

So, you FIRST call `function1` with no arguments (which will presumably run incorrectly, as you didn't pass the search string - and resulted in `uninitialized value $search in concatenation` error you mentioned in the comment), and assign an empty array results into `@array`.

THEN, you call `function1` **again**, this time correctly (passing $search parameter), but ignore the return value (so `@array` will remain empty from first call).

Same problems for second function.

This should have been:

```
my @array = function1($search);
my $arrayvalue = function2(@array);
```

---

Second big problem is that you are passing along the data as an array to a second function, but inside the function assigning it as a scalar (presumably as if you passed an array reference).

Your code:

```
# Called via "function2(@array)";
my @array = $_[0];
```

If you intend to pass an array, you need to process the parameter array as a whole array:

```
# Called via "function2(@array)";
my @array = @_;
```

Whereas if you intend to pass-by-reference, as a single array reference parameter (which is more advanced of a technique but stongly recommended over passing an array for a variety of reasons):

```
# Called via "function2(\@array)";
# Notice the "\" in front of "@" - this is a "take a reference" operator
my $arrayRef = $_[0]; # We only take 1 parameter, the array reference, now
my @array = @$arrayRef; # Dereference array ref into an array. 
# You can also use arrayref directly instead once you learn about data structures
```